# AYUDA ERROR: java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, netbeans, jframe

Gracias al amigo Ivan Clavijos por ayudarme anteriormente, ahora sale otro error pero esta vez no se porque sale : **may 22, 2018 4:49:21 PM ventanas.inscripciones btn_guardarActionPerformed
GRAVE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**

Si Alguien tiene la respuesta se los agradecería muchísimo

```js
package ventanas;

import clases.Conexion;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;


public class inscripciones extends javax.swing.JFrame {

     Connection con= null;
     Statement stmt= null;
     
    public inscripciones() {
        initComponents();
        this.setTitle("INSCRIPCIONES");
        this.setLocation(220,100);
        this.setResizable(false);
        ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Valeria\\Documents\\java\\NetBeansProjects\\atletas\\src\\imagenes\\IND.png");
        this.setIconImage(icono.getImage());
    }
     
    
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txt_ci = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txt_apellido = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txt_telefono = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jScrollPane4 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txt_nombre = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jScrollPane5 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txt_2002 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jScrollPane6 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txt_direccion = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane7 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextPane7 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane8 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txt_2000 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jScrollPane9 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txt_2001 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btn_regresar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn_guardar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cmb_sexo = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel13 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        txt_ci.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txt_ciKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(txt_ci);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 190, 130, -1));

        txt_apellido.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txt_apellidoKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(txt_apellido);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 150, 130, -1));

        txt_telefono.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txt_telefonoKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(txt_telefono);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(380, 110, 130, -1));

        txt_nombre.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txt_nombreKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane4.setViewportView(txt_nombre);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 110, 130, -1));

        jScrollPane5.setViewportView(txt_2002);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(400, 260, 50, -1));

        jScrollPane6.setViewportView(txt_direccion);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane6, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(380, 150, 130, -1));

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Nombre:");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 110, -1, -1));

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Apellido:");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 150, -1, -1));

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("C.I:");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(40, 190, -1, -1));

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        jLabel6.setText("Telefono:");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel6, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(300, 110, -1, -1));

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        jLabel7.setText("Dirección:");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel7, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(290, 150, -1, -1));

        jLabel8.setText("ID:");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel8, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(540, 80, -1, 20));

        jTextPane7.setEditable(false);
        jScrollPane7.setViewportView(jTextPane7);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane7, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(560, 80, 20, 20));

        jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel9.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 51, 204));
        jLabel9.setText("Marcas");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel9, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(410, 180, -1, -1));

        jScrollPane8.setViewportView(txt_2000);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane8, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(400, 220, 50, -1));

        jScrollPane9.setViewportView(txt_2001);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane9, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(520, 220, 50, -1));

        jLabel10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel10.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 204));
        jLabel10.setText("2000");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel10, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(350, 220, -1, -1));

        jLabel11.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel11.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 51, 204));
        jLabel11.setText("2001");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel11, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(470, 220, -1, -1));

        jLabel12.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel12.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 204));
        jLabel12.setText("2002");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel12, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(350, 260, -1, -1));

        btn_regresar.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        btn_regresar.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        btn_regresar.setText("Regresar");
        btn_regresar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btn_regresarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(btn_regresar, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(160, 330, -1, -1));

        btn_guardar.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        btn_guardar.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        btn_guardar.setText("Guardar");
        btn_guardar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btn_guardarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(btn_guardar, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(390, 330, -1, -1));

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sitka Display", 3, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Ingresar los datos del Atleta:");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 10, -1, -1));

        cmb_sexo.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Seleccione", "Femenino ", "Masculino" }));
        getContentPane().add(cmb_sexo, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 230, -1, -1));

        jLabel13.setText("Sexo:");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel13, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(40, 230, -1, -1));

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/SLATO.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 670, 390));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btn_regresarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        Menuopciones Menuopciones= new Menuopciones();
        Menuopciones.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    }                                            

    private void txt_nombreKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
        char validar= evt.getKeyChar();
     if (Character.isDigit(validar)){
         getToolkit().beep();
         
         evt.consume();
     }
    }                                   

    private void txt_apellidoKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
        char validar= evt.getKeyChar();
     if (Character.isDigit(validar)){
         getToolkit().beep();
         
         evt.consume();
     }
    }                                     

    private void txt_ciKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
        char c= evt.getKeyChar();
      if ( c<'0' || c>'9') evt.consume();
    }                               

    private void txt_telefonoKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
       char c= evt.getKeyChar();
      if ( c<'0' || c>'9') evt.consume();
    }                                     

    private void btn_guardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
       
     String cadena2,cadena3,cadena4,cadena5,cadena6,cadena7,cadena8,cadena9,cadena10;
        
        cadena2 = txt_nombre.getText();
        cadena3 = txt_apellido.getText();
        cadena4 = txt_ci.getText();
        cadena5 = cmb_sexo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        cadena6 = txt_telefono.getText();
        cadena7 = txt_direccion.getText();
        cadena8 = txt_2000.getText();
        cadena9 = txt_2001.getText();
        cadena10= txt_2002.getText();
        
        
        if (txt_nombre.getText().equals("") || (txt_apellido.getText().equals("")) || (txt_ci.getText().equals("")) || (cmb_sexo.getSelectedItem().equals(null)) || (txt_telefono.getText().equals(""))
           || (txt_direccion.getText().equals("")) || (txt_2000.getText().equals("")) || (txt_2001.getText().equals("")) || (txt_2002.getText().equals(""))) {
            
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Debe llenar todos los campos \n","AVISO!",javax.swing.JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            txt_nombre.requestFocus();
    
       Conexion conn= new Conexion();
       Connection Connection = conn.getConnection();

        
      } 
        else {
        try {
           
            
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atletas";
            String usuario = "root";
            String contraseña = "vale2109";
            
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
             con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,contraseña); 
             if ( con != null ) 
                    System.out.println("Se ha establecido una conexión a la base de datos " +  
                                       "\n " + url ); 
  
                  stmt = con.createStatement(); 
                  stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO participantes VALUES('" + 0 + "','"+cadena2+"','"+cadena3+"','"+cadena4+"','"+cadena5+"','"+cadena6+"','"+cadena7+"','"+cadena8+"','"+cadena9+"','"+cadena10+"')");
                  System.out.println("Los valores han sido agregados a la base de datos ");
                 
        
                  
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           
       } 
        finally {
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                    stmt.close();
                } catch ( Exception e ) { 
                         System.out.println( "ClassNotFoundException : " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
         javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Registro exitoso! \n","AVISO!",javax.swing.JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        this.txt_nombre.setText("");
        this.txt_apellido.setText("");
        this.txt_ci.setText("");
        this.txt_telefono.setText("");
        this.txt_direccion.setText("");
        this.txt_2000.setText("");
        this.txt_2001.setText("");
        this.txt_2002.setText("");
         

        
        
    }                                           

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(inscripciones.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(inscripciones.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(inscripciones.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(inscripciones.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new inscripciones().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btn_guardar;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn_regresar;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> cmb_sexo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel13;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane4;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane5;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane6;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane7;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane8;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane9;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane7;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane txt_2000;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane txt_2001;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane txt_2002;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane txt_apellido;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane txt_ci;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane txt_direccion;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane txt_nombre;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane txt_telefono;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private void setRezisable(boolean b) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías revisar la cantidad de campos que posees en el insert a base de datos y chequear que se equipare a la cantidad de campos reales existentes en la misma. Tienes en tu query 10 valores a insertar en la tabla participantes, cuenta por favor si posees exactamente 10 campos en dicha tabla.

Comment: Agrega una imagen de tus base de datos para validar la entrada, el error como tal es del motor sql asi que falta info de la tabla.

Comment: `cadena2`, `cadena3` no son nombres expresivos.  Debes de nombrar tus variables con algo que te ayude a identificar que es lo que se supone que contengan.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono :) .